# Place a block of text and a responsive image on the same line in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

A part of a website that I am building I would like the following:
 An image and a `float:right;` div next to each other, like this:

```
============================================
|                                          |
|  bla bla text                            |
|                                          |
| ============                             |
| | IMG      |     Is this the real life?  |
| |Responsive|      Is this just fantasy?  |
| ============                             |
============================================
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ApJaH9j7zV) look at the issue

I can get this working with a normal image but not with a responsive one.
Is there a reason this shouldn't work? or a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a `div` with a class of "row" that contains two other `div` like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x120"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">I want to be on the right side of the responsive image</div>
</div>
```

This way you can ensure that the layout will adapt to screen sizes as well. When on mobile or tablet the image and text will stack atop one another for easier readability. 
You can see this in action here: http://www.bootply.com/h5BGLsTqYd